# python Beautifulsoup count element which has no content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to count element which has no content? 
By saying element which has no content, I mean `<div class="myclass" id="myid"></div>`

Here is the code I wrote with attempting to achieve the goal:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<dl>
    <dt class="details-row-7">Overall</dt>
    <dd id="c0r11" class=" alternate details-row-7">
        <div class="mobile-headings">Overall</div>
        <div class="mobile-value">
            <div class="ca-rating-star" data-size="1"><i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star-empty icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
ele = soup.find("dd", {"id": "c0r11"}, {"class": "alternate details-row-7"})
if ele.find(text=False):
    con_str = ele.find("div", {"class":"mobile-value"})
    if con_str.find(text=False):
        star_ele = con_str.find("div", {"class":"ca-rating-star"})
        if star_ele.find(text=False):
            star = star_ele.find_all("i", {"class":"icon-star icon-1x"})
            i = 0
            for s in star:
                if s.find(text=False):
                    i += 1
            print(i)
```

But the result is 0.....

Answer (score 1):

I answered your question in a gist here.

https://gist.github.com/greatghoul/c2fab58e798a91a736a4

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're looking for children of the `<i>` elements where `text=False` when you say `s.find(text=False)`, but the `<i>` tags don't have children.  You want to see if the `<i>` tags themselves have empty text.  So replace `s.find(text=False)` with `s.get_text() == ""`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<dl>
    <dt class="details-row-7">Overall</dt>
    <dd id="c0r11" class=" alternate details-row-7">
        <div class="mobile-headings">Overall</div>
        <div class="mobile-value">
            <div class="ca-rating-star" data-size="1"><i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
                <i class="icon-star-empty icon-1x" style="color: #FF9900"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
ele = soup.find("dd", {"id": "c0r11"}, {"class": "alternate details-row-7"})
if ele.find(text=False):
    con_str = ele.find("div", {"class":"mobile-value"})
    if con_str.find(text=False):
        star_ele = con_str.find("div", {"class":"ca-rating-star"})
        if star_ele.find(text=False):
            star = star_ele.find_all("i", {"class":"icon-star icon-1x"})
            i = 0
            for s in star:
                if s.get_text() == "": # CHANGE ON THIS LINE
                    i += 1
            print(i)
```